# Laravel livewire how to trigger syncInput without typing in the input?

Tags: laravel

Is it possible to trigger syncInput with javascript only? I want livewire trigger syncInput when I run this script

```
<input wire:model="foo" id="input" type="number">

$('#input').val(123);
```

Comment: with livewire , you can add jquery , but it is optional, instead inside your livewire class, within public function mount() add $this->foo = 123

Comment: thanks for your reply, but im looking for a way to trigger syncInput without typing in the input, there is nothing to do with mount()

Comment: I apologize, can you please clearify what you mean by syncInput ?

Comment: another trick is by adding the following to your js  ... window.livewire.emit('addInputFoo', 123); and inside your livewire component ...  public function addInputFoo(int $value) { $this->foo = $value; .. or add any other process/code you like }

Comment: when you make changes in input livewire will send an ajax request to server to sync the input and re-render the component,  i want to fire this event when i use javascript to change the input value

Comment: is there any other way except emit?

Comment: i suggest you check the documentation https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/reference#global-livewire-js

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with inline scripts you can use the following method to access the component

[Check the docs here](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/inline-scripts#accessing-javascript-component-instance)

Here's an example: directly from the docs

```html
<script>
    document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
        // Get the value of the "count" property
        var someValue = @this.count
 
        // Set the value of the "count" property
        @this.count = 5
 
        // Call the increment component action
        @this.increment()
 
        // Run a callback when an event ("foo") is emitted from this component
        @this.on('foo', () => {})
    })
</script>
```

the `@this` directive compiles to the following string for JavaScript to interpret: "Livewire.find([component-id])"